# remove single quote from all directory and file names

Tags: sed

I ran a sed command recently and I mistyped the command (yes it happens).

So now i have directory and file names that look like `'Call of Duty'`. How can I recursively go back and rename all files and directories to remove the `'`?

this is the command i ran `find . -type f -name "*.css" -exec sed -i'' -e 's|http://cdn|//cdn|g' {} +`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that that is actually the filename? On recent Linux distributions `ls` displays filenames with spaces in quotes by default. Try `ls -N` to be sure.

From the man page:

```
       -N, --literal
              print entry names without quoting
```